# How do I set a collation on a find_raw_batches query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I need to search through a Mongo database collection using an index that has a particular collation set. However, when I call `db[coll].find_raw_batches(filter=filter, collation=collation)`, the collation does not seem to be propagated to the server as part of the find request. I have managed to reproduce this in an isolated setting with the following code:

```
import pymongo
  from pymongo import MongoClient
  from pymongo.collation import Collation, CollationStrength

  def main():
    collection_name = 'test'
    mongo_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017' # some running mongo instance
    client = MongoClient(mongo_url)
    try:
      db = client.get_database()

      # drop existing collection
      collection = db[collection_name]
      collection.drop()
        
      # create indexes
      collection.create_index([('test', pymongo.TEXT)], language_override='index_lang', default_language='en')
      collation = Collation('en', strength=CollationStrength.SECONDARY)
      collection.create_index('not_text', collation=collation)

      # run a dummy query
      filter={'$or': [{'$text': {'$search': 'test text'}}, {'not_text': {'$eq': 'test not-text'}}]}
      cursor = collection.find_raw_batches(filter=filter, collation=collation)
      touch_cursor(cursor)
  finally:
    client.close()

  def touch_cursor(cursor):
    for item in cursor:
      break

  if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the error that I get:

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: database error: error processing query: ns=test.testTree: $or
>
> not_text $eq "test not-text"
>
> TEXT : query=test text, language=english, caseSensitive=0, diacriticSensitive=0, tag=NULL
>
> Sort: {}
>
> Proj: {}
>
> planner returned error: Failed to produce a solution for TEXT under OR - other non-TEXT clauses under OR have to be indexed as well.

The same thing works if I use `find` instead of `find_raw_batches`. My reading of the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_raw_batches) says that this should be supported for both `find` and `find_raw_batches`, but somehow collation is getting lost when using `find_raw_batches`.

Note that combining index-with-collation with a text index only makes the problem more obvious. In the same scenario as above, a query on the `'not_text'` field would not end up being case-insensitive even though the collation dictates otherwise.

So my question is: how do I (can I?) make this work?